# Any way to make this more generic?

Tags: c#, coding-style, dry

I have these two functions, used to search for a folder within a hierarchy:

```
public Folder<T> Find (string Path)
  {
  Folder<T> Result = null;

  if (this.Path != Path &&
      ChildrenDict != null)
    {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<long, Folder<T>> Child in ChildrenDict)
      {
      Result = Child.Value.Find (Path);
      }
    }

  else
    {
    Result = this;
    }

  return Result;
  }

public Folder<T> Find (long ID)
  {
  Folder<T> Result = null;

  if (this.ID != ID &&
      ChildrenDict != null)
    {
    foreach (KeyValuePair<long, Folder<T>> Child in ChildrenDict)
      {
      Result = Child.Value.Find (ID);
      }
    }

  else
    {
    Result = this;
    }

  return Result;
  }
```

As you can see, they are very similar to one another. How can I re-structure them so I don't have essentially the same code several times, one per each property I might want to use to find them?

Comment: You could create an intermediate object which indentifies a folder, like ``string Path`` and ``long ID`` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method with a condition parameter which does the logic:

```
protected Folder<T> Find(Func<Folder<T>, bool> condition) {
    Folder<T> Result = null;
    if(!condition(this) && ChildrenDict != null) {
        foreach(var Child in ChildrenDict) {
            Result = Child.Value.Find(condition);
        }
    } else {
        Result = this;
    }
    return Result;
}
```

Rewrite your public `Find` methods as:

```
public Folder<T> Find(string path) {
   return Find(f => f.Path == path);
}
```